# phpMyAdmin auth not with mysql credentials

Tags: phpmyadmin

I wish to set up an HTTP authentication for phpMyAdmin that does not use the existing mysql users.

I have this options for $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']

```
 string ['HTTP'|'http'|'cookie'|'config'|'signon']
```

None allows me to define an username/password combo. Any suggestions?
Maybe this file can help?

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#authentication_modes details that you would want to use 'config' authentication mode.

Comment: seems to be correct, although I dont need it anymore. Thanks

Comment: The URL has changed to https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-authentication-modes